Telegram bot not sending messages
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode response;

    char* token = "wont post my bot token here";
    char* channel_id = "2041832290";
    char* url;

    sprintf(url, "https://api.telegram.org/bot%s/sendMessage", token);
    
    char post_fields[100];
    sprintf(post_fields, "chat_id=%s&text=%s", channel_id, "Hello");

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, post_fields);

        response = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

        if (response != CURLE_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(response));
        }
    }
    
    printf("%s", response);

    return 0;
}

Bot has admin privileges, is in my telegram channel i checked if the channel_id is correct 300times, I have no errors nothing the bot just doesn't seem to send the message whatsoever

Try with the enabled CURLOPT_VERBOSE. printf("%s", response) is a buggy code. Yet another bug char* url; sprintf(url, ...

I'm not totally very good with C/C++ but some key missing part I could notice was:

char* url is not initialized or assigned memory space before it is used.

Can you try the following code works:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode response;

    char *token = "BOT_TOKEN";
    char *channel_id = "CHANNEL_ID";

    // Allocate memory for url
    char *url = (char *)malloc(256);

    sprintf(url, "https://api.telegram.org/bot%s/sendMessage", token);

    char post_fields[100];
    sprintf(post_fields, "chat_id=%s&text=%s", channel_id, "Hello");

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, post_fields);

        response = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

        if (response != CURLE_OK)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(response));
        }
    }

    // Free dynamically allocated memory
    free(url);

    return 0;
}

I ran it like:
gcc bot.c -o main -lcurl && ./main

Hope this helps!
